# CSS3 vertical Ribbon

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm looking for CSS3 code for the ribbon as below, please?

This is what it should look like this and size width 30px and height 44px:
I don't have any code to offer for sample or something to work from e.g JS fiddles.

[align top http://www.kerrydeaf.com/pink.png](http://www.kerrydeaf.com/pink.png)

I've seen this http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/ribbon/

But it is horizontally. I'm looking for vertical like the above.

UPDATE Monday, 10 December 2.30pm:
**@Zoltan Toth** - I've included a JS Fiddle on comments as below. 
(I'm not allowed to post JS fiffles here).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try something like this - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/QSByU/16/)

***HTML***

```
<div> i </div>
```

***CSS***

```
div {
    background: deeppink;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    font: 600 16px sans-serif;
    color: white;
    line-height: 27px;
    border: 0;
}

div:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -18px;
    left: 0;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    border: solid 15px deeppink;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
}

div:hover {
    background: purple;
}

div:hover:after {
    border-color: purple;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
}​
```

Comment: It's also quite easy to do [without `:after`](http://jsfiddle.net/QSByU/2/) if it won't contain content.

Comment: Is that all? Never thought it would be so easy.

Comment: @ icktoofay - How do I do exact 44 pixels height, the one - without :after.

Comment: I'd like to add a small "i" icon inside it, is that possible and change colour on hover/onTouch?

Comment: This is fabulous and ready to accept the answer. I notice this doesn't leave enough room with "i" as I'm hoping to include an icon logo inside it on <div> but the "i" barely fits in if I adjust the overall height 44px and "i" is pushed on top (more like squeezed on top) as there is little room to breathe.

Comment: :) just apply a lower `z-index` to the `:after` - http://jsfiddle.net/QSByU/33/  I've changed its' color so you can see that the main div actually covers it and you can use the whole space now

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've tried to add "i" icon and it appear off sync in both pink and blue colour. I'm not sure how to solve this?  http://jsfiddle.net/alma/AdgPY/6/

Comment: that's easy :) you have 2 style definitions for background - one for the color and later another one for the BG image. So the first one is getting overwritten and you have no color anymore. To fix that just combine the 2 rules into one - http://jsfiddle.net/AdgPY/7/

Comment: Perfect. Just one more, is it possible to have the ribbon less pointy as it is 90 degree to 75 degree to give more breathing room?

Comment: it was a lot of questions in this one :D  but yes - you can change the border width http://jsfiddle.net/AdgPY/10/

Comment: I know, sorry, Zoltan. http://jsfiddle.net/alma/AdgPY/15/  I've this js fiddle. It look fine. When I've viewed it on ios stimulator, a "i" icon slightly cut off the bottom of "i" icon white circle. How do I prevent that?

Comment: It look better it is down by 2px? Is that possible? And have the ribbon pointy part behind the rectangle area so the icon circle wouldn't be cut off?

Answer (score 0):

Put it inside a DIV, then in the div do this:

```
div
{
transform:rotate(90deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(90deg); /* IE 9 */
-moz-transform:rotate(90deg); /* Firefox */
-webkit-transform:rotate(90deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transform:rotate(90deg); /* Opera */
}
```

Or you can use Canvas for that and drawn however you want, and don't need that CSS2 tricks to do that.

Comment: I'd like to add a small "i" icon inside it, is that possible and change colour on hover/onTouch?

Answer (score 0):

Vertical banner with slanted bottom

[image]

```
<div class="verticalbanner"></div>

.verticalbanner {
    background: #e22692; //ribbon color
    height: 44px; // ribbon height
    width: 30px; // ribbon width
}
.verticalbanner:after,.verticalbanner:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-top: 20px solid #e22692; // angle degree, reduce to reduce degree of angles
    height: 0; // no height, no content, just border
    width: 0;
    top: 100%;
}
.verticalbanner:after { // right angle
    border-left: 25px solid transparent;
    right:0;
}
.verticalbanner:before { // left angle
    border-right: 25px solid transparent;
    left:0;
}
```

[jsFiddle (link)](http://jsfiddle.net/davidcondrey/hrpc418m/2/)